# The trick to Pantheon's ult

Tags: league-of-legends

Pantheon's ult, if used improperly, is life threatening to say the least. I've had a lot of issues with it. One being it is only effective 5% of the time. The other is that it can be interrupted, when interrupted a 8 second cooldown comes up, then it resets the cooldown completely (atleast it appears that way) and, timing the ult with such a long channeling time.

Typically, the only time I've had it be really effective is when I communicate with another lane to CC the opponent as im jumping on top of them. Otherwise I'll ult on top of someone and if I do it right they might use all their escapes to get away from it, which is good I guess.

Things I've learned not to do is chase with it, or jumping on top of a turret with 2 or more opponents trying to take it or tower diving with it.

Has anyone come across some tricks that let you actually get good use out of it?

Comment: Practice, communication, and **some luck**, are all you need. (as if that wasn't much)

Comment: Use it on your enemy for a free teleport :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a professional Pantheon player but here is what I've found:

First off you got it right by coordinating with your teammates CC, and getting rid of all of their escape is typically good (unlessy you're talking about abilities in which case they just have to wait a few seconds and do it again)

It usually works better when the teams are engaged too because then you give your opponent the tough choice of either finishing the engage but taking damage from your ult and facing a pantheon, or running away and taking free damage as they run. Another one is locking them in, which requires teammates that can take them on if they would rather avoid your ult than run through it. Example would be a low health mid laner and your mid lane is chasing, jumping in front of the path that the opponent is running will cut them off leaving them to either run back and die or die to you. I'm asuming that when you used it to chase someone who is escaping and failed it was primarily because you were in a 1v1 scenario, but even if your damage doesn't go off forcing your opponent to make tough decisions like those are what really makes the difference. If the target has a way to get out without any penalty don't use it, simple as that. Also typically you want to be away from a team fight when you use ult so that it doesn't get canceled. Even if the enemy team didn't have any way of canceling your ult, you may be better off saving it and doing even more damage with your other abilities and auto attacking: remember pantheons ult takes time, and time is damage. Id say another trick understanding his ult is typically you're not trying to get kills with it alone. Yes there are times where there are close team fights and a pantheon ult will kill one or two of them, but those are the obvious ones, most of the time you'll be coordinating it with teammates to take down a few escaping opponents or protect your dying teammates from a losing team fight byt intimidating them. Don't dive teams, and don't dive turrets (often), try to focus on "does this help your team get more damage off to win a fight and/or get an objective" rather than "will I get a kill or will I die". Hope this was the answer you were looking for!

P.S. another step ahead of this would be to ask is panths ult even really useful? As I have explained most of the time you give your opponent the choice in most senarios. Granted this sometimes leaves them with a lose lose choice but if they have the choice then they have the opportunity to gain an advantage if they make the right choice. It's all about thinking ahead and making sure that doesn't happen and not wasting your ult unless you know for certain it will work for the benefit of the team.

Comment: Also its important to know Panth's  ult makes a great escape.

Comment: So much text, you could format this answer a bit better.

Comment: Yeah, I was having a hard time figuring out how to format the answer to be less of a jumble of words. Definitely something to improve on my next answer :) @LTPro

Comment: Also, don't forget you can cancel your ult manually.

Answer (score 3):

There's only one trick that I know of, and I haven't touched Panth since early season 2:

**Somehow, you can aim your Aegis of Zeonia during the fall (post-channel part of Skyfall) and kind of skew your trajectory (the damage is still applied in the target circle, but you land next to an opponent).**

This was a long time ago, yes, but I clearly remember this scenario:

> *An underfed enemy Shaco was pushing a lane. I targeted him with Skyfall and locked in with the Aegis. He burned both his Flash and Deceive, and
>   I still landed next to him and stunned him. He was invisible during
>   the stun, so I threw HSS in front of me. When Shaco became visible, I
>   could clearly see I've successfully hit him. The only thing that
>   remained was an auto-attack (which I landed while he was stunned) and
>   a Spear Shot to finish him off.*

He did dodge the damage of Skyfall, but because back then I used 3 Bloodthirsters (it worked back then, *somehow*) one single combo *100-to-0*'d him.

Comment: can someone confirm that this still works

Comment: It is an intended part of Skyfalls mechanic that if the enemy is in the SECOND CIRCLE as it forms you can Aegis them ahead of time so that as soon as you land you immidiatly jump to them and stun them. This only works if they are still somewhere in the circle when you land.

Comment: @Ender That's the thing. Back when I did it, the Shaco basically double-flashed away and I STILL got him. He was WAAY out of the circle.

Comment: as much as I like the idea, I would like to know if this is still up to date.

Comment: @user1337 I've had him jump on me when I was out the circle too, maybe I'm misunderstanding the mechanics? I assumed I was just in a grip of annoyance and exaggerated my escape.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. If the enemy is outside of your circle when you land, your aegis doesn't jump to him anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the best plays I have seen with Pantheon involve split pushing. When the enemy comes to stop Panth's split, you ult to the lane your team is in. This gives you a 5v4 in your favor. In this scenario the ult can be aimed to clear a minion wave or initiate and scatter the enemy team. Patheon with teleport can wreak havoc on unprepared teams due to his ability to be almost anywhere on the map at a moment's notice.

The offensive plays, where you want to land on someone's head, are usually most effective when the team fight has started. Once the enemy team is "all-in" they will be less likely to scatter. If they don't scatter, you deal lots of damage to those in the landing area. If they do scatter, well that is just as effective really since your allies should be able to pick-off the loners.

Answer (score 1):

Besides some answers given by locking out paths from the enemy, and Pantheon ulting on a teamfight can break it up by letting some enemies flee (and thus taking free damage or burning escapes), I'd like to point out Pantheon excels in split-pushing. You can compare it with Shen or Twisted Fate for that matter. Pantheon has the ability to push a lane quickly and build pressure on a lane. If the team pushes the botlane and you are pushing the top lane, the enemy team has to split up to make sure no towers are lost. If so, Pantheon can ult the other lane, instantly creating an extra player to the pushing team, or even landing on top of the enemy (towerdiving) and securing a kill. Pantheon's passive block can block a tower hit and can let Pantheon get away without taking too much damage.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

there was a trick i think there still is. when ult into a team fight use the triple passive block there is a way to keep three, have a flash. i think its patched, but right before you land use flash right before you hit and you create two ult hits into the ground. team charges in and you get team fight win